# Extending instead of Implementing an interface

Tags: java, interface

Please consider the following two files defined in the same package in eclipse.

**PData.java**

```
package com.abc.cast.q;


public class PData<F extends SF> {
```

**SF.java**

```
package com.abc.cast.q;
public interface SF{

  String getCName();

}
```

I am going through the code and noticed that the in PDData, F is extending SF, however, after looking SF.java, I came to know that it's an interface. So,in `PData.java` shouldn't it be  `F implements SF` instead of `F extends SF` in this case?

The compiler doesn't complains

Comment: PData<F extends SF>  -> which is generics, introduced in java 5 different from inheritance.

Comment: `Class`es implement `interface`, but a `interface` can `extend` other `interface`. Implementation (`implements`) means defining the behavior while `extends` means extending the features/operation which can be performed.

Comment: @YoungHobbit In my case, Class is extending interface, so the above code is wrong? But that is happening inside `< >`

Comment: `PData<F extends SF>` this is not extending. this is called generics. Essentially it says, you are defining operations/behavior which are best suited to `F extends SF` types.

Comment: @YoungHobbit So, here I can say that a variable `F` is extending the class `SF` ? How would I interpret it?

Comment: I hope this will help in understanding the above [Bounded Type Parameters](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bounded.html).